# How to read and write DDR memory in FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I am not good at English. sorry.

I don't know if the content of the question is too abstract.

I'm going to build a Neural Network Hardware Accelerator with Artix 7 FPGA.
However, block memory is out of capacity.
So I'm going to use DDR3 memory, which is included on the arty a7 board.

I want to write the value in the block memory to DDR memory or read the value in DDR memory.

Is there a good way to read and write DDR memory on the FPGA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the Artix-7 product summary. They mention DD3 memory support and the datasheet mentions DDR memory controllers.

You have to find Xilinx' information about the Artix DDR controller and read through it.  Probably it has an AXI interface as Xilinx is very much into AXI these days. If so you have to write an AXI master interface to read from or write to the DDR. Or maybe Xilinx have some IP which does most of the work.

None of the above is easy! Start with installing the latest Vivado design suit (it is free) which gives you also Xilinx' docnav. You will need it as the documentation of Xilinx is reasonably good but there is **a lot and a lot and a lot** of it.

I'll be honest: this is not something I would recommended a begginner with HDL to do unless you are prepared to put a lot of time it (and also learn a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a memory controller IP from Xilinx. See https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf (to begin with).